# CocoaPod Result name conflict

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, moya

I'm using the pod `Moya` in my code and one of it's dependencies is a `Result` enum.

I also have another `Result` enum in my code and it's conflicting with this one.

How can I use `Result.Result` for this enum?
I'm getting the error Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in <...> as if it thinking it's the enum, not the namespace.

Or is there another solution like changing the name of the import?

as in `import Result as MoyaResult`.

Answer (score 1):

Moya uses Alamofire, which has it's own `Result` type. You can disambiguate by referring to that `Result` as `Alamofire.Result`. Or you can prepend your app's module name to your `Result` type in a similar fashion.

Comment: In my case it seems like it's using Result.Result, not Alamofire.Result, and the first one gives me that error.